# Microsoft graph api planner task bulk insertion

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, asp.net-core-3.1, microsoft-graph-plannertasks

We are using microsoft graph api v1.0 in our .Net core application from planner tasks crud operations.
Steps we are performing are:

1. Create group
2. Create planner plan
3. Create multiple tasks under above group and plan.

Sometimes everything works fine but some times some task fails.
We loop our tasks list and do post call through graph api sdk for c#.

We get 400 or 500 randomly while creating plan under group on multiple retries, it creates sucessfully.

Some times on planner task post call we get 400 or 500 response.

Any idea how we can do these batch calls without missing tasks

Comment: Is the error permanent - do you get 400 or 500 for a specific task? Are there some error details (like, "invalid task name" or something)?

Comment: Please capture and share request ids and time stamps for the operations. Plan may be failing because the new group information may not be available to read immediately after creation. 400 and 500 are not normal error conditions, we'll need the tracing information to look into it.

Comment: Mainly we are getting from plan after creating group as group information isnt available right after its creation. 
Is there any way to make it smooth?

Comment: You do not have the required permissions to access this item, or the item may not exist.
We face this Error

Answer (score 0):

These might be the reasons why 400 errors might be happening as mentioned in the docs

[image]

For more information:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/planner-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0#common-planner-error-conditions

These are the ways to create a planner and to avoid the 400 errors: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/planner-post-plans?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#response

Hope this helps.